# protractor configuration problems when running

Tags: protractor

Just started working on npm and Protractor but was unable to resolve this. I have installed protractor v3.3.0, npm 3.9.0. Webdriver works well

```
λ protractor conf.js
[14:00:04] E/configParser - error code: 105
[14:00:04] E/configParser - description: failed loading configuration file conf.js

> C:\Users\JohnTest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:130
>             throw new exitCodes_1.ConfigError(logger, 'failed loading configuration file ' + filename);
>             ^  Error
>     at ConfigError.ProtractorError (C:\Users\JohnTest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:10:22)
>     at new ConfigError (C:\Users\JohnTest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\exitCodes.js:26:16)
>     at ConfigParser.addFileConfig (C:\Users\JohnTest\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\configParser.js:130:19)
>     at Object.initFn [as init] (C:\Users\jj07251\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\launcher.js:94:22)
>     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\jj07251\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\protractor\built\cli.js:130:10)
>     at Module._compile (module.js:409:26)
>     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:416:10)
>     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
>     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
>     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

Comment: Post your protractor config.

Comment: Does the file `conf.js` exist in the current directory? If so, what is in it? If not.... you need to make one.

Answer (score 1):

Give the exact path, i.e `"e2e-tests/protractor.conf.js"` (as it is in my case).
And if it still gives some error, add these lines to your `protractor.conf.js` file-

```
chromeOnly: true,
directConnect: true
```

Hopefully this should work!

*(PS- when I gave the command "`protractor conf.js`", it gave me the same error)*

Answer (score 0):

Go into the directory where the conf.js is located and run protractor from there.